# Grid sorting with Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I am using the Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI Grid to show a grid on an Asp.Net MVC website.

All of the columns are supposed to be sortable / filterable, but as you will see from the image below, the only who that actually do have a Sort / Filter in the right place are the File Name column and the Project Requested By column.

[image: Screen shot of my page...]

These columns are bound by the following code...

```
        c.Bound(o => o.FileName);
        c.Bound(o => o.Dto.ProjectDetailsDto.ProjectRequiredBy)
            .Template(o => o.Dto.ProjectDetailsDto.ProjectRequiredBy.HasValue ? o.Dto.ProjectDetailsDto.ProjectRequiredBy.Value.ToString(Model.DateTimePattern) : "")
            .HeaderHtmlAttributes(Resources.EditorLocalization.ProjectDeadline);
```

Let's limit the problem, and ask ourselves why the Project Name is not sortable (it isn't). The project name is bound like so :

```
            c.Bound(o => o.Dto.ProjectName)
            .Template(o => Html.ActionLink(o.Dto.ProjectName, "Details", "Project", new { projectId = o.Dto.AssetTask.ProjectId }, null))
            .HeaderTemplate(Resources.EditorLocalization.ProjectName)
            .Sortable(true)
            .Filterable(true);
```

First of all, I considered that it might be that columns that use a template cannot be sorted - only they can, because we have the working case of the Project Required By Column.

Perhaps, I thought, it is the presence of the HeaderTemplate() that is causing us problems, but then why would it? Still, I can't deny, everything I believe should work, but doesn't, has a HeaderTemplate.

So - let's blame that and see what we can do... The reason I am using a HeaderTemplate is because we want to be able to be able to localise the strings used to label the columns (ie the headers). Is there any other approach we might take which would allow us to do that, but also mean we could have sorting on the grid as well?

Thanks in anticpation...

Answer (score 0):

Ok - the problem was indeed down to my use of HeaderTemplate(). If I use the Title() method instead, all is well...